# Jenkins. Russian locale settings in Windows 2019 server docker image

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins, settings, locale

Jenkins. How to set russian locale settings in Windows 2019 server docker image?

[image: Russian locale settings]

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage
[image: Register keys - codepages]

We have non-Unicode Delphi6 application using 1251 codepage (windows russian cyrillic). We compile it with dcc32.exe in command line. In Jenkins, it compiles incorrectly, russian strings - with unreadible symbols.

We tried to compile application on Windows 2019 server itself, it compiles right with right locale settings (see above).

We tried to set locale like this:

```
docker.image('mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019').inside("...") {
environment {
  LC_ALL = 'ru_RU'
  LANG    = 'ru_RU'
  LANGUAGE = 'ru_RU'
}

bat 'building_app.cmd'
```

or like this:

```
docker.image('mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019').inside("...") {
environment {
  LC_ALL = 'ru_RU.WIN1251'
  LANG    = 'ru_RU.WIN1251'
  LANGUAGE = 'ru_RU.WIN1251'
}

bat 'building_app.cmd'
```

or like this:

```
docker.image('mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019').inside("...") {                        
powershell 'Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale ru-RU'
powershell 'Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Nls\\CodePage" -Name "ACP" -Value "1251"'

bat 'building_app.cmd'
```

but it all has no effect. As we understood, locale settings must be set BEFORE running docker, not afterwads. It must be set in image.

How to do this?